# Traversing the DOM children of children

Tags: javascript, dom, traversal, children

why children of a children of an element doesn't return me the the  element, instead gives me undefined?

```js
let val;
const list      = document.querySelector('.collection');
const listItems = document.querySelector('.collection-item');

val = list.children;
val = val[3].children.children;
console.log(val);
```

```html
<ul class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item">
      <a class="secondary-content" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
      <a class="secondary-content" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
      <a class="secondary-content" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `children.children` doesn’t exist

Comment: `val = val[3]` Remember that JS starts counting at zero. With only 3 children, this would be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector('.collection')` is a method that returns an HTMLElement object matching any elements containing the "collection" CSS class ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Return_value)).

`val = list.children` is a property and will return an HTMLCollection (an ordered collection, ie. a **list**) of any children of the `list` node.
Being that it the `children` property returns a list, you can access the individual nodes in the collection by using either the `item()` method on the collection, or by using array-style notation. See [ParentNode.children (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).

Lastly; with the `val[3]` call, remember that JS array iterations start at 0. To get the third item in the val list/array, you'd use `val[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

So, the `children` return `HTMLCollection` then you have to attach `index` when getting new children:

```js
let val;
const list      = document.querySelector('.collection');
const listItems = document.querySelector('.collection-item');

val = list.children;
val = val[2].children[0].children; 
console.log(val);
```

```html
<ul class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item">
      <a class="secondary-content" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
      <a class="secondary-content" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li class="collection-item">
      <a class="secondary-content" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.children` is an `HTMLCollection`, which works like an Array. As such, it doesn't have a `.children` parameter.

You need to loop through the array or select an item:

`val = list.children[0].children`

or

`list.children.forEach(child => console.log(child.children))`

Comment: [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) is not an array, it is an `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that part of his code. He saves the `children` HTMLCollection and then does the same thing as you're suggesting

Comment: except he calls `.children.children`

Comment: Oh right, missed that part. Seems 2 issues here. First wrong index, then wrong selector

Answer (score 0):

A NodeList / HTML Collection returned from the `.children` property comprises of the parentElement direct descendants (ie children -- ***not children of children***).  If you want to use `.children` to get to the *"grandchildren"* you'll need to iterate through both `.children` collections or if you have a childElement in mind then bracket notation would be effective (ex. `parentElement.children[1]`) **BTW** the index number in bracket notation is 0-index based so for example `.children[2]` is actually the third element and so on.

#### Demo

```js
// Reference the <ul>
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

/*
Collect each <li> in <ul> into a NodeListr then 
convert it into a real Array with the bracket and 
spread operator (ie [...NodeList]
*/// itemsA and itemsB are identical
const itemsA = [...list.querySelectorAll('.item')];
const itemsB = [...list.children];

/*
Since the OP objective was vague...the following are console logs that verify the results. 
The last console log is my best guess as to what the OP's objective was.
*/
console.log(` .list direct descendants (aka children):\n
${itemsB.map(item => ` <${item.tagName.toLowerCase()} class="${item.className}">...<\/${item.tagName.toLowerCase()}>\n`)}`);

console.log(`Array itemsA (as htmlString):\n
${itemsA.map(item => item.outerHTML)}`);

console.log(`Array itemsB (as htmlString):\n
${itemsB.map(item => item.outerHTML)}`);

console.log(`Third .item of .list (as htmlString):\n
${itemsA[2].outerHTML}`);

console.log(`Third .item of .list deepest descendant:\n
${[...itemsB[2].children].flatMap((node, index) => node.children[index].outerHTML)}`);
```

```css
.list {
  list-style: none
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 14px
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 375px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.as-console-row {
  border-bottom: 5px ridge #333
}

.as-console-row-code::first-line {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after,
.as-console-row-code.as-console-row-code::after {
  content:'';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <a class="link" href="#/">
        ITEM 1 <i class="fas fa-minus-square"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a class="link" href="#/">
        ITEM 2 <i class="fas fa-minus-square"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a class="link" href="#/">
        ITEM 3 <i class="fas fa-minus-square"></i>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you everybody. Your answers were really helpful !!